# PostgreSQL trigger for inserting an entry in table2 AFTER a row is inserted in table1 (using the values from newly inserted row in table1)

Tags: postgresql, triggers, database-trigger, postgresql-9.3

I have displayed my database schema below.

```
CREATE TABLE table_group
(
    group_id serial NOT NULL,
    group_creator_id integer NOT NULL,
    group_name character varying(20) NOT NULL,
    active_status boolean NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (group_id),
)

CREATE TABLE table_group_members
(
    group_member_id serial NOT NULL,
    group_id integer REFERENCES table_group (group_id) NOT NULL,
    member_user_id integer REFERENCES table_group (group_creator_id) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (group_member_id)
)
```

I want to INSERT a new row in the table `table_group_members` as soon a new row is inserted in table `table_group`.

I want to pass the `group_id` and `group_creator_id` of the newly inserted row in the table `table_group` as parameters to INSERT query for the table `table_group_members`

How should I do it using the PostgreSQL TRIGGER?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: I point you at [trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html). Look at Example 42.4. A PL/pgSQL Trigger Function for Auditing. That will give you the basic principles. If there is something you don't understand then add to your question.

Comment: Why do you care if it is before vs after?  They will be in the same transaction, so both "occur" at the same time from the outside view.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks for the answer. Got the solution.

Comment: @jjanes The main reason for ```AFTER``` triggers is catch the state of the row after any ```BEFORE``` triggers have possibly modified the inbound data.  So though they occur in the same transaction they may see different data. Not sure this is the case here.